# How can I write a SQL query to list distinct values and their number of occurrences from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scada

I have a table that contains a history of alarm events.
I think the only pertinent column for this is Message, but there are others such as Time/Date and Source.

Here's a sample table:

| Time/Date | Message | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:28 | Code 1 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:37 | Code 4 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:39 | Code 1 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:42 | Code2 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:44 | Code 1 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:46 | Code 3 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:48 | Code 1 | VFD1 |
| 2022-04-27/11:59:50 | Code 2 | VFD1 |

From this, I'd like to create something like this:

| Message | Occurrences |
| --- | --- |
| Code 1 | 4 |
| Code 2 | 2 |
| Code 3 | 1 |
| Code 4 | 1 |

This is being done inside a SCADA software package (ICONICS/Genesis64), so I'm not sure of the exact flavor of SQL, but I think it should be Microsoft SQL Server or similar to it.

I can run this:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT Message) as Messages FROM dm_Alarms
```

to get how many unique values I have, but I'm stuck on how to count for each unique value, and then list them.

And I do NOT know what all values I will possibly have for Message, it could be very many and change over time.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you just need to aggregate?

```
select Message, count(*) Occurrences
from dm_Alarms
group by Message;
```

Comment: Thank you, that gets me where I needed to go. Clearly have a lot to learn still. I'm not sure if using count(*) vs count(Message) matters, I notice that the first includes null Message values, and the latter does not.

Comment: Yes count(*) counts all rows, count(column) will ignore nulls - use whichever gives the desired results.